# AWS Amplify custom domain giving 403 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I wanna connect an Amplify object to a domain from 3rd-party domain supplier. and I got the 403 access denied Error when make a request.

with Amplify Guide Docs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-google-domains.html

I set up a CNAME indicating the domain provided from Amplify like "master.12sgfkjhsdgsdr.amplifyapp.com" in DNS management settings.